# Always redirect from any domain prefix to www.example.com with iis url rewrite rule

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

we have a site at something.example.com and we want it to go always redirect to www.example.com

We already have the rule in for 'adding' www. when a user just puts example.com.

But we have a test url that is in place for other reasons and we want the live site to ALWAYS redirect to www.example.com no matter what prefix it has before the domain.

Answer (score 0):

**just use this regex `.*` in `<match url="" />` or IIS URL re-write pattern field**

---

for additional information:

1. dot means any single char
2. Asterix means zero or more of a char

> so `.*` means zero or more of any char

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use {http_host} to match the domain part in the url rewrite rule.

Details, you could refer to below rules:

```
            <rule name="rediect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*).example.com" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
```